# Probability-throwing a die

Tags: probability

Three players $X,Y,Z$ play with die. There is order to throwing: $XYZXYZ...$.
What is the probability that the first "$6$" would be thrown by $X$, the second "$6$" by $Y$ and the third by $Z$.

I have any idea how to solve it. Do you help me? Which tools should I use?

Comment: If you are totally baffled as to how to start: You might give some thought to the situation in which there are only *two* players, $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Hint: The probability that the first player gets the first six is equal to the probability that the second player gets the second six if the first player gets the first six - can you figure out why?

Comment: noo, I can't see it

Comment: Well done: you posted a zero-input question, somebody brought you an excellent suggestion to start working on it (namely, to solve the two players case), but you did nothing of the sort and, since somebody else soon posted a full answer, you got what you were after: zero brain activity and a solution to hand back to your TA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ throws the first six, then everyone throws a non-six until he throws it. So the probability is $\frac{1}{6}(1+\lambda+\lambda^2\dots)$ where $\lambda=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$. That sums to $\frac{1}{6(1-\lambda)}=\frac{36}{91}$.

Once he has thrown the six, the prob that the next six is thrown by $Y$ is the same (because $Y$ is the first to throw after $X$'s success). Similarly for $Z$. So we get $\left(\frac{36}{91}\right)^3\approx6.2\%$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first round of $XYZ$, the respective probabilities of $X,Y,Z$ winning are:

$\dfrac16,\; \dfrac56\dfrac16, \; \dfrac56\dfrac56\dfrac16$

so the odds in favor are $36:30:25\;$ respectively, and will be the same in each such cycle.

Thus the respective probabilities for $X,Y,Z$ throwing the $6$ first are $\dfrac{36}{91}, \dfrac{30}{91}$ and $\dfrac{25}{91}$

---

Oh, you want the probability of $X$ throwing the first six, $Y$ throwing the second.....

So once $X$ has thrown the first $6$, $Y$ is now in the same position as $X$ was at start,

so $P(Y$ throws the second $6) = \left(\dfrac{36}{91}\right)^2$

and similarly, $P(Z$ throws the third $6) = \left(\dfrac{36}{91}\right)^3$